# Need help rearranging a list

Tags: list

I need help on getting an interpreter to work. I have this 'bumpkin' code as a list right here.

```
LET A 1
GOSUB 6   <------ goes to line 6 of 'bumpkin' code (index starts at 1). 
PRINT A
PRINT B
END
LET A 2
LET B 3
RETURN   <------- returns to GOSUB 6 and continues on down list
```

Technically what GOSUB does is that it goes to the specified line (in this case line 6) and continues down until it hits RETURN and goes back to it again and continues on.

So technically while going in a downward fashion in the list, the GOSUB skips around the list a bit until it gets a call signal RETURN and then returns to the GOSUB line and continues downward again.

The main problem is that I don't know how to do this and append it to a new list so it becomes a new list of objects so I can execute it. The resulting new list would be:

```
LET A 1
LET A 2
LET B 3
PRINT A
PRINT B
END
```

I was curious how I would approach this. I can't use a for loop because then it'll loop through the entire 'bumpkin' code and parse them. I can't skip any lines with a loop.

Many thanks!

EDIT===========================================================EDIT

So heres my Python code so far:

```
oldlist = [['LET', 'A', '1'],
           ['GOSUB', '6'],
           ['PRINT', 'A'],
           ['PRINT', 'B'],
           ['END'],
           ['LET', 'A', '2'],
           ['LET', 'B', '3'],
           ['RETURN'],
           ['.']]

newlist = []

def NewLister():
    ProgramCounter = 0
    funcbool = True
    while funcbool:
        if oldlist[ProgramCounter][0] == 'LET':
            newlist.append(oldlist[ProgramCounter])
            ProgramCounter += 1
            print(newlist)
        elif oldlist[ProgramCounter][0] == 'GOSUB':
            pass # <---------------------No Idea how to get this working
        elif oldlist[ProgramCounter][0] == 'PRINT':
            pass 
        elif oldlist[ProgramCounter][0] == 'END':
            pass
```

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: I'm supposed to write an interpreter in Python 3.3.2 that would parse that 'bumpkin' code you see up there. 

For clarification, that 'bumpkin' code are just commands just like regular user inputs that my Python interpreter would need to work with.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is an academic exercise and the language is not relevant so I'm going to talk in concepts rather than code.

You need to implement a stack.  You push items onto the stack and pop them off of the stack.  When you hit a GOSUB, push the line # where execution should resume.  When you hit a RETURN pop the top value off the stack and resume execution at that line.

Consider this slightly altered version of your code...

```
LET A 1
GOSUB 6   <------ goes to line 6 of 'bumpkin' code (index starts at 1). 
PRINT A
PRINT B
END
LET A 2
LET B 3
GOSUB 10
RETURN 
DO SOMETHING 
RETURN
```

When you hit the first GOSUB you push 3 onto the stack.  Now it looks like

```
Stack
---------
3
```

Start executing at line 6, when you hit the GOSUB 10, push 9 onto the stack.  Now it looks like

```
Stack
---------
9
3
```

Start executing at line 10.  When you hit the return you pop the top value off the stack, which is 9.  So resume execution at line 9.  The next return pops a value of 3, resume execution at line 3.

Comment: The language isn't relevant. But I cannot change the 'bumpkin' code. Sorry, for clarification. The 'bumpkin' code is literally just commands my Python interpreter has to parse. The user pastes those commands in a text file, and my interpreter has to parse them giving an output.

Comment: He hasn't changed the bumpkin code, he is describing how to implement a VM.

Comment: The change to your example code was just too demonstrate multiple gosubs and how a stack works.